# Determine Shortest Distance between two moving points

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, physics, matplotlib-animation

Im am trying to produce the shortest distance between the two orbiting points (Earth and Jupiter) created by this orbital model. I'vebeen working on this for quite some time but have been struggling.

Could someone sugest a way to create this output or possibly create a line connecting the two points and display their distance reative to one another? Ideally in km but AU is fine too.

I'm new to programming so any help would be great.

Thank you in advance!

This is the code ive been using on Google Colab;

`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Untitled2.ipynb

Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14vpwJ9ixq6YZGSxN2eBWay-hIPe__BxF
"""

#%% plot it 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['animation.embed_limit'] = 2**128
#matplotlib.use("TkAgg") # for mac M1
from IPython.display import HTML

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)

from tempfile import TemporaryFile
# First to define the Constants
G           = 6.67e-11
Ms          = 1.988e30                    # Sun
Me          = 5.972e24                    # Earth        
Mj          = 1.898e27                    # Jupiter
AU          = 1.5e11
daysec      = 24.0*60*60

e_ap_v      = 29780                   # Earth's velocity
j_ap_v      = 13060                   # Jupiter's velocity

gravconst_e = G*Me*Ms
gravconst_j = G*Mj*Ms

# To setup the starting conditions and locations on plot of each planet;

# Earth
xe,ye,ze    = 0,(1*AU),0
xve,yve,zve = -e_ap_v,0,0

# Jupiter
xj,yj,zj    = 0,(5.2*AU),0
xvj,yvj,zvj = -j_ap_v,0,0

# Sun
xs,ys,zs    = 0,0,0
xvs,yvs,zvs = 0,0,0

t           = 0.0
dt          = 1*daysec # every frame move this time

xelist,yelist,zelist = [],[],[]
xslist,yslist,zslist = [],[],[]
xjlist,yjlist,zjlist = [],[],[]

# start simulation
while t<1*365*daysec:
    ################ earth #############
    # compute G force on earth
    #rx,ry,rz = xs - xe, ys - ye, zs - ze
    rx,ry,rz = xe - xs, ye - ys, ze - zs
    modr3_e = (rx**2+ry**2+rz**2)**1.5
    fx_e = -gravconst_e*rx/modr3_e
    fy_e = -gravconst_e*ry/modr3_e
    fz_e = -gravconst_e*rz/modr3_e
    
    # update quantities how is this calculated?  F = ma -> a = F/m
    xve += fx_e*dt/Me
    yve += fy_e*dt/Me
    zve += fz_e*dt/Me
    
    # update position
    xe += xve*dt
    ye += yve*dt 
    ze += zve*dt
    
    # save the position in list
    xelist.append(xe)
    yelist.append(ye)
    zelist.append(ze)
    
    ################ Jupiter ##############
    # compute G force on Jupiter
    rx_j,ry_j,rz_j = xj - xs, yj - ys, zj - zs
    modr3_j = (rx_j**2+ry_j**2+rz_j**2)**1.5
    fx_j = -gravconst_j*rx_j/modr3_j
    fy_j = -gravconst_j*ry_j/modr3_j
    fz_j = -gravconst_j*rz_j/modr3_j
    
    xvj += fx_j*dt/Mj
    yvj += fy_j*dt/Mj
    zvj += fz_j*dt/Mj
    
    # update position
    xj += xvj*dt
    yj += yvj*dt
    zj += zvj*dt
    
    # add to list
    xjlist.append(xj)
    yjlist.append(yj)
    zjlist.append(zj)
    
    ################ the sun ###########
    # update quantities how is this calculated?  F = ma -> a = F/m
    xvs += -(fx_e+fx_j)*dt/Ms
    yvs += -(fy_e+fy_j)*dt/Ms
    zvs += -(fz_e+fz_j)*dt/Ms
    
    # update position
    xs += xvs*dt
    ys += yvs*dt 
    zs += zvs*dt
    xslist.append(xs)
    yslist.append(ys)
    zslist.append(zs)
    
    # update dt
    t +=dt

# to plot the data  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['animation.embed_limit'] = 2**128
from IPython.display import HTML

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5.8,5.8))
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# Defining the planets and orbit path attributes on the graph (size & colour)
line_e,     = ax.plot([],[],'b',lw=3,)
point_e,    = ax.plot([AU], [0], marker="o", markersize=5, markeredgecolor="green", markerfacecolor="blue")
text_e      = ax.text(AU,0,'Earth')

line_j,     = ax.plot([],[],'r',lw=3)
point_j,    = ax.plot([5.2*AU], [0], marker="o", markersize=7, markeredgecolor="red", markerfacecolor="brown")
text_j      = ax.text(5.2*AU,0,'Jupiter')

point_s,    = ax.plot([0], [0], marker="o", markersize=10, markeredgecolor="orange", markerfacecolor="yellow")
text_s      = ax.text(0,0,'Sun')

exdata,eydata = [],[]                   # earth track
sxdata,sydata = [],[]                   # sun track
jxdata,jydata = [],[]                   # Jupiters track

print(len(xelist))

def update(i):
    exdata.append(xelist[i])
    eydata.append(yelist[i])
    
    jxdata.append(xjlist[i])
    jydata.append(yjlist[i])
    
    line_e.set_data(exdata,eydata)
    point_e.set_data(xelist[i],yelist[i])
    text_e.set_position((xelist[i],yelist[i]))
    
    line_j.set_data(jxdata,jydata)
    point_j.set_data(xjlist[i],yjlist[i])
    text_j.set_position((xjlist[i],yjlist[i]))
    
    point_s.set_data(xslist[i],yslist[i])
    text_s.set_position((xslist[i],yslist[i]))
    
    ax.set_xlim(-5.8*AU,5.8*AU)
    ax.set_ylim(-5.8*AU,5.8*AU)
    return line_e,point_s,point_e,line_j,point_j,text_e,text_j,text_s,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,func=update,frames=len(xelist),interval=1,blit=True)


# Showing animation in Jupyter Notebook 
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(anim.to_jshtml())
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and get some tips on [ask]. To get better result and help from this community for your question, please: 1/ make a clear statement on what is the issue you are facing, what error or wrong result you are having, 2/ reduce your code to a [mcve], 3/ include an example input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

The connection line between Jupiter and the Earth can be drawn using the `arrow` method of matplotlib. This allows to add arrow heads if desired. The distance can be added as a normal label.

```
annotation  = ax.arrow(0, AU, 0, (5.2 - 1) * AU)
text_a      = ax.text(0, (5.2 + 1) / 2 * AU, '', ha='center', backgroundcolor='white')
```

In the update method the distance has to be calculated using the Pythagorean theorem:

```
    annotation.set_data(x=exdata[-1], y=eydata[-1], dx=jxdata[-1] - exdata[-1], dy=jydata[-1] - eydata[-1])
    text_a.set_position(((exdata[-1] + jxdata[-1]) / 2, (eydata[-1] + jydata[-1]) / 2))
    text_a.set_text(f"{dist/1e9:.1f} Mio km")
```

Whole code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Untitled2.ipynb

Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14vpwJ9ixq6YZGSxN2eBWay-hIPe__BxF
"""

#%% plot it 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['animation.embed_limit'] = 2**128
#matplotlib.use("TkAgg") # for mac M1
from IPython.display import HTML
from math import sqrt

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)

from tempfile import TemporaryFile
# First to define the Constants
G           = 6.67e-11
Ms          = 1.988e30                    # Sun
Me          = 5.972e24                    # Earth        
Mj          = 1.898e27                    # Jupiter
AU          = 1.5e11
daysec      = 24.0*60*60

e_ap_v      = 29780                   # Earth's velocity
j_ap_v      = 13060                   # Jupiter's velocity

gravconst_e = G*Me*Ms
gravconst_j = G*Mj*Ms

# To setup the starting conditions and locations on plot of each planet;

# Earth
xe,ye,ze    = 0,(1*AU),0
xve,yve,zve = -e_ap_v,0,0

# Jupiter
xj,yj,zj    = 0,(5.2*AU),0
xvj,yvj,zvj = -j_ap_v,0,0

# Sun
xs,ys,zs    = 0,0,0
xvs,yvs,zvs = 0,0,0

t           = 0.0
dt          = 1*daysec # every frame move this time

xelist,yelist,zelist = [],[],[]
xslist,yslist,zslist = [],[],[]
xjlist,yjlist,zjlist = [],[],[]

# start simulation
while t<1*365*daysec:
    ################ earth #############
    # compute G force on earth
    #rx,ry,rz = xs - xe, ys - ye, zs - ze
    rx,ry,rz = xe - xs, ye - ys, ze - zs
    modr3_e = (rx**2+ry**2+rz**2)**1.5
    fx_e = -gravconst_e*rx/modr3_e
    fy_e = -gravconst_e*ry/modr3_e
    fz_e = -gravconst_e*rz/modr3_e
    
    # update quantities how is this calculated?  F = ma -> a = F/m
    xve += fx_e*dt/Me
    yve += fy_e*dt/Me
    zve += fz_e*dt/Me
    
    # update position
    xe += xve*dt
    ye += yve*dt 
    ze += zve*dt
    
    # save the position in list
    xelist.append(xe)
    yelist.append(ye)
    zelist.append(ze)
    
    ################ Jupiter ##############
    # compute G force on Jupiter
    rx_j,ry_j,rz_j = xj - xs, yj - ys, zj - zs
    modr3_j = (rx_j**2+ry_j**2+rz_j**2)**1.5
    fx_j = -gravconst_j*rx_j/modr3_j
    fy_j = -gravconst_j*ry_j/modr3_j
    fz_j = -gravconst_j*rz_j/modr3_j
    
    xvj += fx_j*dt/Mj
    yvj += fy_j*dt/Mj
    zvj += fz_j*dt/Mj
    
    # update position
    xj += xvj*dt
    yj += yvj*dt
    zj += zvj*dt
    
    # add to list
    xjlist.append(xj)
    yjlist.append(yj)
    zjlist.append(zj)
    
    ################ the sun ###########
    # update quantities how is this calculated?  F = ma -> a = F/m
    xvs += -(fx_e+fx_j)*dt/Ms
    yvs += -(fy_e+fy_j)*dt/Ms
    zvs += -(fz_e+fz_j)*dt/Ms
    
    # update position
    xs += xvs*dt
    ys += yvs*dt 
    zs += zvs*dt
    xslist.append(xs)
    yslist.append(ys)
    zslist.append(zs)
    
    # update dt
    t +=dt

# to plot the data  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['animation.embed_limit'] = 2**128
from IPython.display import HTML

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5.8,5.8))
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# Defining the planets and orbit path attributes on the graph (size & colour)
line_e,     = ax.plot([],[],'b',lw=3,)
point_e,    = ax.plot([AU], [0], marker="o", markersize=5, markeredgecolor="green", markerfacecolor="blue")
text_e      = ax.text(AU,0,'Earth')

line_j,     = ax.plot([],[],'r',lw=3)
point_j,    = ax.plot([5.2*AU], [0], marker="o", markersize=7, markeredgecolor="red", markerfacecolor="brown")
text_j      = ax.text(5.2*AU,0,'Jupiter')

point_s,    = ax.plot([0], [0], marker="o", markersize=10, markeredgecolor="orange", markerfacecolor="yellow")
text_s      = ax.text(0,0,'Sun')

annotation  = ax.arrow(0, AU, 0, (5.2 - 1) * AU)
text_a      = ax.text(0, (5.2 + 1) / 2 * AU, '', ha='center', backgroundcolor='white')

exdata,eydata = [],[]                   # earth track
sxdata,sydata = [],[]                   # sun track
jxdata,jydata = [],[]                   # Jupiters track

print(len(xelist))

def update(i):
    exdata.append(xelist[i])
    eydata.append(yelist[i])
    
    jxdata.append(xjlist[i])
    jydata.append(yjlist[i])
    
    line_e.set_data(exdata,eydata)
    point_e.set_data(xelist[i],yelist[i])
    text_e.set_position((xelist[i],yelist[i]))
    
    line_j.set_data(jxdata,jydata)
    point_j.set_data(xjlist[i],yjlist[i])
    text_j.set_position((xjlist[i],yjlist[i]))
    
    point_s.set_data(xslist[i],yslist[i])
    text_s.set_position((xslist[i],yslist[i]))
    
    ax.set_xlim(-5.8*AU,5.8*AU)
    ax.set_ylim(-5.8*AU,5.8*AU)
    
    dist = sqrt((exdata[-1] - jxdata[-1])**2 + (eydata[-1] - jydata[-1])**2)
    
    annotation.set_data(x=exdata[-1], y=eydata[-1], dx=jxdata[-1] - exdata[-1], dy=jydata[-1] - eydata[-1])
    text_a.set_position(((exdata[-1] + jxdata[-1]) / 2, (eydata[-1] + jydata[-1]) / 2))
    text_a.set_text(f"{dist/1e9:.1f} Mio km")
    
    return line_e,point_s,point_e,line_j,point_j,text_e,text_j,text_s,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,func=update,frames=len(xelist),interval=1,blit=True)


# Showing animation in Jupyter Notebook 
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(anim.to_jshtml())
```

Comment: Hi @M472 , Thank you very much for yiur response and answer to my question, it was greatly appreciated. When I ran your annonated code into my Google Colab, I received this error;       annotation.set_data(x=exdata[-1], y=eydata[-1], dx=jxdata[-1] - exdata[-1], dy=jydata[-1] - eydata[-1])     
AttributeError: 'FancyArrow' object has no attribute 'set_data'.... Do you possibly know how to fix this. Thanks again

Comment: The problem seems to be an older version of matplotlib running on Google Colab. I was working with matplotlib 3.5.3 on my machine, Google Colab is using 3.2.2.
I have been able to get my solution running on Colab by upgrading matplotlib. To do this you can add `pip install --upgrade matplotlib==3.5.3` in a Colab notebook cell. You may have to restart the runtime afterwards (Main Menu > Runtime > Restart Runtime).